# I am trying to write a query to track use of terminals. I want to show all terminals that have not had activity for 1 year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query to track the use of PC terminals. I want to show all PC terminals that have not had activity for 1 year. This is the query that I am trying to use and it returns 0 results even though I know I have terminals that have not been used. The dates are in as date/time formats (2016-06-22 14:38:12.000)

```
select distinct 
   t.Terminalid, 
   t.TerminalName
from 
   Terminal as t
Inner Join 
   Pos_Payments as p 
   on p.TerminalId = t.TerminalId
where 
   TransactionDateTime < '7/29/2015' and TransactionDateTime !> '7/30/2015'
order by t.TerminalID
```

Comment: `!>` you should look at this...

Comment: Would you edit into your question the schema for these tables? What format, in particular, are your dates in - strings, dates or datetimes?

Comment: I assume `!>` is intended to mean `not greater than` - do you know that works? I assume it would be better to use `<=` instead, i.e. `less than or equal`, but I don't  know if that is what you mean here.

Comment: You should  use ISO standard operators, but your where logic returns rows that are before 7/29 and not after 7/30 which is redundant.

Comment: I have terminals that had activity before 7/29 and after 7/30. I do not want to see any terminal that has had activity after 7/30/2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and `max()`:

```
select t.Terminalid, t.TerminalName
from Terminal t Inner Join 
     Pos_Payments p 
     on p.TerminalId = t.TerminalId
group by t.Terminalid, t.TerminalName
having max(TransactionDateTime) < '2015-07-29'
order by t.TerminalID ;
```

Note the use of the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD date format.

If you want this based on the current date:

```
having max(TransactionDateTime) < dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
```

(And you might want to cast that to `date` to get rid of the time component.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives me exactly what I was looking for.